# File Permissions - How to let app read all files within a specific folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-permissions

I'd like to make an app that has access to a specific folder(s) and can read all the folders / files inside of it. What type of access does that require? Are there any libraries for this in Ruby? How do I list files in a specific directory and read their contents?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dir` and `File` from ruby standard library. following script will read all the files in current directory and output its size to screen

```
Dir['*.*'].each do |name|
  puts File.open(name).size
end
```

Please refer to ruby documentation for more commands regarding these classes.

[Dir rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D)

[File rubydoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html)

Comment: There's also FileUtils, which as few nice bits and pieces in it.

Comment: thank you. Much easier than anticipated.